# using GR as a Matplotlib backend to increase speed

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to use Matplotlib, embedded in tkinter, but the plotting is too slow for my needs. My data is a bar graph with ~9000 values. Some research showed that GR may be useful for speeding up matplotlib.

According to wiki.python.org,

"GR can also be used as a backend for Matplotlib and speed up existing applications. The GR framework is especially suitable for real-time environments."

However, I am having trouble changing the MPL backend to GR. I found this page on the GR website which seemed like it would be helpful

https://gr-framework.org/tutorials/matplotlib.html

When I run the commands they suggest, I get errors.

```
python artist_reference.py -dmodule://gr.matplotlib.backend_gr
```

Gives me the error "python: can't open file 'artist_reference.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

As for the command

```
export MPLBACKEND="module://gr.matplotlib.backend_gr"
```

I'm not sure whether to run this in cmd or in my python script. Either way I have had no success.

Could someone please help me find the proper way of using GR to improve my matplotlib performance? I would rather not switch to a new plotting library and rewrite all my code. The following link may also help people who are more knowledgeable figure out how this works.

http://gr-framework.org/tutorials/mpl_interop.html

Comment: `artist_reference.py` would need to be replaced by the name of the file with your script. `export MPLBACKEND=...` is to be written in the command line. Generally, see [backends](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends).

Comment: Thanks! I've now set the backend to "module://gr.matplotlib.backend_gr". However, when I try to run the py script I get an error saying this is an unrecognized backend string. The error lists other backend strings such as GTK3Agg and Qt5Agg. Is there a way to add gr to the accepted backends?

Comment: Sounds like you have not (or unsuccessfully) installed `gr`.

Comment: I ended up adding matplotlib.use("module://gr.matplotlib.backend_gr") at the top of my program. This seemed to work, as it raised no errors, but the performance continued to be slow. I'm going to search for alternative methods to improve speed of plotting, as this did not seem to be as helpful as I'd hoped.

Comment: Feel free to make your particular problem clear in this (or a new) question. Speed is an inherent problem to matplotlib, but to some standard problems there are solutions around.